# Select line below search expression in log file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am trying to search logs for an expression, then select the line below each match.

#### Example

I know I want the lines below CommonText, for example given the log data:

```
CommonTerm: something
This Should
random stuff
CommonTerm: something else
Be The
random stuff
more random stuff
CommonTerm: something else
Output Text
random fluff
```

#### Desired Output

```
This Should
Be The
Output Text
```

#### Current Attempt

Currently I can use `grep log_file CommonTerm -B 0 -A 1` to get:

```
CommonTerm: something
This Should
--
CommonTerm: something else
Be The
--
CommonTerm: something else
Output Text
```

I can then pipe this through `| grep "\-\-" -B 0 -A 1` to get

```
This Should
--
--
Be The
--
--
Output Text
--
```

And then through `awk '{if (count++%3==0) print $0;}'`, giving:

```
This Should
Be The
Output Text
```

My question is: surely there's a good 'unix-y' way to do this? Multi greps and a hacky awk feels pretty silly... Is there?

Edit: I also tried:

```
(grep 'CommonTerm:' log_file -B 0 -A 2) | grep "\-\-" -B 1 -A 0 | grep -v "^--$"
```

but it seems much more clunky than the answers below which was expected ;)

### Edit:

There are some great answers coming in, are there any which would let me easily select the **nth** line after the search term? I see a few might be more easy than others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n "/^CommonTerm: /{n;p}" log_file
```

This searches for "CommonTerm: " at the start of the line (`^`), then skips to the next line (`n`) and prints it (`p`).

**EDIT**: As per the comment thread, if you're using BSD `sed` rather than GNU `sed` (likely to be the case on OS X), you need a couple of extra semicolons to get round a bug:

```
sed -n "/^CommonTerm: /{;n;p;}" log_file
```

Comment: `sed: 1: "/^CommonTerm: /{n;p}": extra characters at the end of p command` ??

Comment: @PeterHamilton are you on OS X, by any chance? If so, you're probably using BSD sed rather than GNU sed (in which case, adding an `-E` flag might help, e.g. `sed -E -n "/^CommonTerm: /{n;p}" log_file`).

Comment: Yes I am indeed! Still no luck unfortunately:

`sed -E -n "/^CommonTerm: /{n;p}" logfile.log
sed: 1: "/^CommonTerm: /{n;p}": extra characters at the end of p command`

Comment: @PeterHamilton Ah ... okay, flying in the dark here now (not an expert on Apple's buggy version of sed), but possibly this might work: `sed -n "/^CommonTerm: /{;n;p;}" log_file`.

Comment: What's the reason for the additional `;`?

Comment: @PeterHamilton Beyond "making BSD sed stop throwing stupid errors", I'm afraid I don't really know ... presumably without them, the braces are erroneously considered to be (parts of) commands. Glad it worked for you in the end, anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'p { print; p=0  }
    /CommonTerm/ { p=1 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
grep -B 0 -A 1 "CommonTerm" log_file | grep -v "^CommonTerm:" | grep -v "^--$"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with awk:

```
awk 'found{found=0;print;next}/CommonTerm/{found=1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that have `pcregrep` installed, this can be done at one shot. Notice the use of `\K` to reset the starting point of the match

```
pcregrep -Mo 'CommonTerm.*?\n\K.*?(?=\n)' file
```